# Why is there a space between the write statements in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

In the following code after the second write statement there is a space inserted and I don't understand why

```
  write(output_line,string'("  when x"""));
  write(output_line,address_map(1 to address_count));
  write(output_line,string'(""""));
```

I expect to get --- when x`"adressmap"`  but instead receive -----when x`"adressmap "`

I do not want this extra space between the p and quotation mark any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: What is the declaration for, and are there any assignments to `address_map`

Comment: yes I am reading a .csv file and inserting an element from the file into address_map it will always be a number and there is no space afterwards @scary_jeff

Comment: What is the type and content of address_map? Also, if you have any choice at all, don't write a code generator in VHDL. It's string handling is rather clumsy. Use Python or maybe even TCL, or really any high-level programming language.

Comment: Is the last byte you want actually at address_count - 1?

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
use std.textio.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    constant address_map: string := "address_map";
    constant address_count: natural := address_map'LENGTH;
begin
    process
        variable output_line: line;
        variable output_line_length: natural;
        variable read_buff: string (1 to 80);

    begin
        write(output_line,string'("  when x"""));
        write(output_line,address_map(1 to address_count));
        write(output_line,string'(""""));
        output_line_length := output_line'length;
        read(output_line, read_buff(1 to output_line_length));
        report "output_line = " & read_buff(1 to output_line_length);
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

I get:

> % foo
>   foo.vhdl:21:9:@0ms:(report note): output_line =   when x"address_map"

Which doesn't demonstrate the extra space in the quoted portion of string accessed to by `output_line`.

This tells us your extra space is coming from some declaration or statement you haven't provided. Your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

It seems likely you're making a mistake with `address_count` in your actual code.

You could note providing an mcve would likely have pointed you to the discrepancy.